# extra padding between structs in C

Tags: c, gcc, memory

I have struct in C:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data; // 4 bytes int + 4 bytes for alignment
    struct Node* prev; // 8 bytes pointer
    struct Node* next; // 8 bytes pointer
} Node;
```

The size of this struct is 24 bytes (8 + 8 + 8). When I use the sizeof(Node), the compiler also shows 24 bytes.

However, when I create two or more structs on the heap (one after another) and look at their memory location, there are 8 byte gaps between each Node struct. 
For example:

```
11121344 (the 1st Node address)
11121376 (the 2nd Node address) // 376-344 = 32-24 = 8 extra bytes
11121408 (the 3rd Node address) // 408-376 = 32-24 = 8 extra bytes
```

Can you explain why compiler separates Node structs by adding 8 bytes between Nodes?

Comment: I would guess the reason is to have the structs word aligned. It facilitates memory access.

Comment: If you created them on the heap, all bets are off wrt to what memory address they get assigned.

Comment: @Genjik Please tell us what _you_ expected and why.

Comment: The secret will be in how you did "create two or more structs". Is this an array? If not why expect the memory addresses to have *anything* to do with each other?

Comment: @gst, are you saying that C-compiler also adds extra padding between structures to access memory more quick?

Comment: @FireLancer, I am creating doubly linked list. Memory for each node is allocated on the heap. Nodes are allocated one after another, and I am expecting memory on the heap to look like this:
24 bytes for the 1st Node
24 bytes for the 2nd Node and so on. 
But, it looks differently:
24 bytes for the 1st.
8 bytes for something unknown to me.
24 bytes for the 2nd.
8 bytes for something unknown.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(Node) * 3)` is an array of 3 structs where you expect certain relative addresses. `malloc(sizeof(Node)); malloc(sizeof(Node)); malloc(sizeof(Node));` is 3 completely unrelated objects that could each be anywhere.

Comment: Did you use `malloc` to create your structs on the heap? In order to bypass alignment problems, `malloc` (and most other functions of the `malloc`-family) will use maximum alignment. Which archictecture are you working with? x86? amd64? In general, however, just as others pointed out, there are no guarantees whatsoever about the memory location if you allocate several memory chunks one after another...

Comment: @FireLancer, got it, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelBeer, I am working on x86_64 and using malloc(sizeof()) function.

Comment: Malloc is also using some memory for its internal bookkeeping (and sometimes also put canaries to detect corruptions).  There are several possible strategies, and some of them may reveal themselves in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 possible reasons for your observation:

1. The C standard requires that `malloc` always returns memory chunks with maximum alignment to prevent alignment issues no matter what you allocate for.
2. `malloc` manages memory chunks internally by using some sort of data structures. Depending on the implementation, it would add additional information to each memory chunk for internal usage. For instance, malloc could manage memory chunks in a linked list, then it would require each chunk to hold an additional pointer that points to the next chunk.

The maximum alignment depends on the architecture and the compiler / `malloc` - implementation used.

For your case and assuming glibc, taken straight out of the docs of `glibc/malloc.c` :

```
 Alignment:                              2 * sizeof(size_t) (default)
       (i.e., 8 byte alignment with 4byte size_t). This suffices for
       nearly all current machines and C compilers. However, you can
       define MALLOC_ALIGNMENT to be wider than this if necessary.
  Minimum overhead per allocated chunk:   4 or 8 bytes
       Each malloced chunk has a hidden word of overhead holding size
       and status information.
  Minimum allocated size: 4-byte ptrs:  16 bytes    (including 4 overhead)
              8-byte ptrs:  24/32 bytes (including, 4/8 overhead)
```

Thus `malloc` in your case will align to `2 * sizeof(size_t) =` 16 bytes.

Also note the 'hidden overhead' mentioned. This overhead is due store additional internal information used for memory management...

Answer (score 3):

> Can you explain why compiler separates Node structs by adding 8 bytes between Nodes?

It's a coincidence. There is no rule about how to lay out memory for any sequence of `malloc()` calls.

The address can be ascending with a fixed interval, descending with varying intervals, (seemingly) random, ..., ....

If you want fixed relative addresses use an array

```
struct Node arr[3];
ptrdiff_t delta10 = &arr[1] - &arr[0];
ptrdiff_t delta20 = &arr[2] - &arr[0];
ptrdiff_t delta21 = &arr[2] - &arr[1];
if (delta10 != delta21) /* cannot happen */;
```

or allocate a group of elements (maybe with `realloc()`) at the same time

```
struct Node *elements = malloc(3 * sizeof *elements);
ptrdiff_t delta10 = &elements[1] - &elements[0];
ptrdiff_t delta20 = &elements[2] - &elements[0];
ptrdiff_t delta21 = &elements[2] - &elements[1];
if (delta10 != delta21) /* cannot happen */;
free(elements);
```

Comment: The behavior is not likely a “coincidence” in the sense of being random chance. It is likely a consequence either of the C standard’s requirement that `malloc` return memory suitably aligned for any object with fundamental alignment requirement or the design of the memory management functions.